# The window object belongs to which class and can we override its properties and methods?

Tags: javascript, html, class, window, overriding

We know that window is an `object`.

[image]

That means that it should be having a `class` (not an *abstract* class), from which it was instantiated. So, my question is what is the **name of that class** and can we `extend` it in some way to make another class which can `override` the existing properties and methods. For example:

```
// Suppose "windowClass" is a class from which window object was instantiated
class windowClass { ... };

class MyWindow extends windowClass {
  constructor() {
    this.width = super.width;
    this.height = super.height;
    ...
    this.onload = super.onload;
  }
}
```

Comment: `That means that it should be having a class`. What? - Just so you know, JS is a prototype-based, classless programming. `window` has existed long before `class`. But sure, you can always override or overload the `window` object. But that's it.

Comment: `You can always override or overload the window object` - Object? You mean to overide an object. How?

Comment: Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ftrz24cf/1/) for it. Hope it helps